# Format Json Response in a Iframe

Tags: json, iframe

Hello I suppose this should be simple but I just cant get the correct answer:)

I have a "simple" json command that I run to get a value , I want to show this value in a Iframe within a page. What I have managed to do is this:

```
<iframe src="https://emoncms.org/feed/value.json?id=169990" name="frame1" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center">
```

and it will show the following response :

"28" 
in plain text.

Is it possible to format the value so that it could be showed as

**28 w** or even maybe change the font ectr.

Comment: I'm guessing emoncms.org is a third-party domain. According to [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), **you can not access or manipulate content from another domain**.

Comment: I sort of hoped that as the value is passed in plain text that I could just format the output value from the json command.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the access to the iframe? If **YES** then you can add the style in body of the iframe or the `pre` tag.

```
pre{
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```